# How to add execution information in allure report in cypress

Tags: cypress, allure

[my report image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lp9tt.png)

i don't know how to integrate allure report execution with our spec it is showing **No information about test execution is available.** . please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate the steps methods of the tests by annotation `@Step("This is a step description done by your autotest")`

P.S. annotation syntax is in Java, you need to find our how to annotate it in JS

Comment: Thanks I will try this.